# Groovy: list.pop() does not work

Tags: java, list, groovy

I have sticky point with a list. After some work I could generate my list and make an xml result. 
But in my list are entries with tabulators or line breaks (the last entry)

If I execute the script, the result is the following:

```
[100, 0100045395, Kurzstrasse, 0502028767496, , 8050, 100, Zürich, 05.07.2010, 
100, 0100045395, 0400053113, 0000356988, , TPS, ZL1, 1549820, 02.06.2010, 
100, 0100045395, 0400053113, 0000356988, , TPS, ZL1, 1549820, 02.06.2010, 
]
```

First of all I will try to remove the last line break with pop()
But I allways get this message:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:   Ljava.lang.String;.pop() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: sum(), dump(), min(), max(), any(), sort()
       at auslesenzwei.xmlGenerieren(auslesenzwei.groovy:44)
        at auslesenzwei.run(auslesenzwei.groovy:37)
```

What I'am doing wrong?

Code:

```
 import groovy.util.CharsetToolkit;
 import java.lang.Object

 //Generate pathname
 //Pfadname generiert für einfacheres ändern des Speicherortes
 def pathname = "C:/mySupport-eclipse/trackandtrace.txt"
 //Define Error Status
 //Error Status definieren für Weiterverabeitung in mySupport
 int errorCode = 0
 def errorMessage = ""

 def linesAsList = []


 def bsknr = "0100045395"
 //Define new File
 //Neue Datei definieren
 def file = new File(pathname)

 if(!file.exists())
{
    errorCode = 1
    errorMessage = "File not found"
    out_xml = xmlGenerieren()   
}
else
{
    //Read Roews and look for BSK Number, split after tab
    //Zeilen einlesen und nach der BSK Nummer suchen, nach dem Tabulator trennen
    def lines = file.filterLine { 
        line -> line ==~ /.*\t${bsknr}\t.*/ 

        }
    //Split the result after tab and enter, give back as String
    //Das Ergebnis aufteilen bei Tabulator und Enter und zugleich als String zurückgeben
    linesAsList = lines.toString().split('\t|\r')
    xmlGenerieren(linesAsList)
        //println linesAsList
    }

 def xmlGenerieren(givenlist) {
     def writer = new StringWriter()
     def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
        //givenlist.pop()
     println givenlist
     def listsize = givenlist.size()


    //Test if is empty
//Prüfen ob ein Ergebnis gefunden wurde
if (listsize == 0)
{
    builder.result() 
    {
        entry(wert:"0")
        {
            paketnr("(empty)")
        }
    }
    println writer.toString()
    errorCode = 0
    }
else {


//i = listsize / 8
//println i

}

}
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.split()` returns an array of Strings, not a List.  Use `String.tokenize()`, or cast the result of split to a list like `linesAsList = lines.toString().split('\t|\r') as List`.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was incorrect; you need to cast the return value of `split` to a List, e.g. `linesAsList = lines.toString().split('\t|\r')
 as List`.

Comment: thank you very much. now I see my mistake. It's already working